# Connecting ActionCable to different host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, actioncable

I'm running a rails 5 app as a backend server, and an ember application for a front-end application.  They are two separate applications hosted on two different domains - say, `backend.dev` and `frontend.dev`

The rails application has a simple connection class found at `app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb` that looks like the following:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    def connect
      Rails.logger.debug("env: #{env.inspect}")
      Rails.logger.info("cookies.signed: #{cookies.signed.inspect}")
    end
  end
end
```

I have a simple base channel class at `app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb` with the following:

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Channel < ActionCable::Channel::Base
  end
end
```

And a single implementation of that class at `app/channels/events_channel.rb`:

```
class EventsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    Rails.logger.debug("env: #{env.inspect}")
    Rails.logger.info("cookies.signed: #{cookies.signed.inspect}")
    stream_from 'events'
  end
end
```

On the ember side of things, I'm using the ember-cable package.  I've setup my consumer in my frontend by extending the controller class with the following:

```
cableService: Ember.inject.service('cable'),

setupConsumer: Ember.on('init', function() {
  let service = this.get('cableService');
  let consumer = service.createConsumer(`ws://backend.dev`);
  let channel = 'EventsChannel';

  consumer.subscriptions.create(channel, {
    disconnected() {
      Ember.debug(`${channel}#disconnected`);
    },

    connected() {
      Ember.debug(`${channel}#connected`);
    },
```

I'm fairly sure that my consumer is setup correctly, as I'm seeing *some* debug output when I get the following output to my js console:

```
DEBUG: EventsChannel#disconnected
```

However, I'm also seeing an odd error in the console as well:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://backend.dev/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

I'm not sure what to make of the response code error here, and there's absolutely nothing being logged in my rails app.  Is there anything additional that I need to setup to have actioncable work across domains?  Any idea of what the 200 response code means here?

Comment: What's in your config/routes.rb? Where are you mounting ActionCable (`/cable`?) It's possible that you just need to add your mount point to your `service.createConsumer` call - you're looking for something like `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'` in routes.rb

Comment: Did you forgot to include  `contentSecurityPolicy` in `config/environment.js` for `connect-src` attribute like this `'connect-src': "'self' ws://backend.dev/ backend.dev",`

Comment: thanks @Undo and @kumkanillam - i'm mounting the ActionCable server using `mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'` - requests to `backend.dev` return the "unexpected response 200" error, while requests to `backend.dev/cable` just produce 404s.  I also have the `connect-src` config setup similarly to the comment above.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # your code
  mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
end
```

Then in your app:

```
let consumer = service.createConsumer(`ws://backend.dev/cable`);
```

---

If you face handshake problems, there are few solutions:

1. Check if your frontend app is compatible with `protocol 07` or newer.
2. Check if your website is in `config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins`
3. Add `config.web_socket_server_url = 'ws://backend.dev/cable'` to your ENV cofig file.
4. You can use a fast "dirty" hack. Just add following to your ENV cofig file:

   ```
   config.action_cable.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
   ```